# Is there a way to pass the wxWidget GUI to a wxThread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have made a game that uses a game loop.
Now i am trying to implement a GUI for this game in wxWidgets.

The problem is that when I initialize the GUI the control of the program remains on a GUI loop and doesn't go to the game loop.

So, can i make the GUI run on its own thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but leave all code, which interacts with the GUI on the main thread/EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). Concurrent access to GUI elements is not intended by design and will cause problems. Instead, put the game loop into a [`wxThread`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread.html) and fire appropriate events from there. Those events can then be handled on the EDT to update the GUI or for rendering a frame.

Another solution would be, to invoke single iterations of your game loop on the main thread, using [`wxTimer`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_timer.html).

Note:

- Throttle the game loop or coalesce the events if necessary. [`wxTimer`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_timer.html) does perfectly support throttling by frequency and coalescing of update events. In a separate thread, you'd need to sleep for the remaining time of the desired cycle/iteration time or wait on a semaphore, triggered by the main thread.
- Implement access to share data like the game state with a synchronization object like [`wxMutex`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_mutex.html). Preferably, you could instead use [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) from C++11.

Examples:

- http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication
- http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Making_a_render_loop